# Can't add multiple object to session in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

When I try to add an item to a cart it only adds it once, if I try doing it again it overwrites it and the item counter remains 1.

I've tried switching from a button to a link, I've tried different routs, and other people solutions to similar problems, I have also tried using the push method instead of put(when I try to save things in the session), but it doesn't work since its an associative array. And I have come to a conclusion that the problem is most likely in the controller file.

my controller

```php
public function getAddToCart(Request $request, $id)
{
    $burgeri = Burgeri::find($id);
    $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
    $cart->add($burgeri, $burgeri->id);

    $request->session()->put('cart',$cart);
    return redirect()->route('burgeri.index');
}
```

Cart.php

```php
class Cart
{
    public $items = null;
    public $totalQuantity = 0;
    public $totalPrice = 0;

    public function __constructor($oldCart)
    {
        if ($oldCart) {
            $this->items = $oldCart->items;
            $this->totalQuantity = $oldCart->totalQuantity;
            $this->totalPrice = $oldCart->totalPrice;
        }
    }

    public function add($item, $id)
    {
        $storedItem = ['quantity' => 0, 'price' => $item->price, 'item' => $item];
        if ($this->items) {
            if (array_key_exists($id, $this->items)) {
                $storedItem = $this->items[$id];
            }
        }
        $storedItem['quantity']++;
        $storedItem['price'] = $item->price * $storedItem['quantity'];
        $this->items[$id] = $storedItem;
        $this->totalQuantity++;
        $this->totalPrice += $item->price;
    }
}
```

`The Blade View`

```html
<button class="cool_btn" onclick="window.location='{{route('burgeri.addToCart', ['id' => $burgeri->id]) }}'">
    Add to Cart
</button>
```

And this is how I display the counter that counts the amount of items in the cart.

```html
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url('Cart') }}">
        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
        Cart
        <span class="badge badge-secondary">{{Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart')->totalQuantity : ''}}</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

When I use the: `dd($request->session()->get('cart'));` method I get the correct item with its parameters but I have no idea why the counter is not working, it is somehow resetting the cart that is stored locally, is my guess.

Thank you for reading this, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are overwriting $storedItem inside if condition

Comment: Though you find that your are writing wrong for constructor, You are also overriding $storedItem inside if(array_key_exist) condition.
if (array_key_exists($id, $this->items)) {
           $storedItem = $this->items[$id];
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry but it turns out I wrote constructor wrong... its construct not constructor,
everything else works as intended

Comment: you can comment under your question. no need to post answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to pass id of item as you are passing object in function callback

```
$cart->add($burgeri);
```

Then stop overriding `$storedItem` in function

```
public function add($item)
{
    $storedItem=['item'=>$item, 'quantity'=>1];
    if($this->items)
    {
       if(array_key_exists($item->id, $this->items))
       {
          $storedItem['quantity']++;
       }
    }
    $storedItem['price']=$item->price * $storedItem['quantity'];
    $this->items[$id]=$storedItem;
    $this->totalQuantity++;
    $this->totalPrice+=$item->price;
}
```